# FileUpload control won't accept 0kb file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, web-controls

I was using blank text files to run some tests, and was going crazy because FileUpload1.HasFile was always coming back false, even though it clearly had a file.  I then switched test files to something above 0 kb (i.e. txt files with text in them), and then it worked.

**As far as I can tell, you can't upload something of 0 kb.  Is this true?**  I read about the FileUpload class on MSDN, but didn't notice anything that says files of 0 kb would be ignored/treated as not a file.

Realistically and practically, I don't see this as being much of a problem (why would you want to upload a blank file?), but I can imagine some kind of rare situation where I might want to reserve a space for something that doesn't have content yet, like a blank text file for a user to fill in when he/she has time.

Comment: try this property `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile.aspx`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [`FileUpload.PostedFile Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile.aspx), that will give you access to the file even if the content is `0` bytes

Comment: Ah, I see.  I was able to use if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null) { article.Attachment1 = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName; }  Thanks.